# HTACCESS: mirror htdocs sub folder to www folder

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

Since my customers hosting providers domain cpanel doesnt have the possibility to create subdomains, I've been trying to figure out how to mirror a subfolder from my htdocs to my root www folder within my .htaccess.

Root: /domains/{domain.com}/htdocs/www/

Sub: /domains/{domain.com}/htdocs/beta/

I need to keep the subdomain {beta.domain.com} intact to let everything work as planned. So when a customer visits {www.domain.com} or {beta.domain.com} he needs to see exact the same site with the domain kept intact.

DOCUMENT_ROOT is '/etc/apache2/htdocs'

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: What is DOCUMENT_ROOT for both domains?

Comment: @anubhava document root is '/etc/apache2/htdocs'

Comment: So in that case what are `/etc/apache2/htdocs/www` and `/etc/apache2/htdocs/beta` paths? I believe `/etc/apache2/htdocs/beta` should be having site content for `beta.domain.com`

Comment: @anubhava /etc/apache2/htdocs/www is the root and contains all the files and content. When the visitor goes to /etc/apache2/htdocs/beta it will get everything within the www folder but with a subdomain.

Comment: Hmm that part I didn't understand. How is `www.domain.com` going to `htdocs/www` when DOCUMENT_ROOT is `htdocs`? Are there any existing rules? Can you post `VirtualHost` section of both sites to make it clear.

Comment: `htdocs` and `htdocs/www` are both the same. I guess they did it this way because of a cleaner look (have no clue haha). Unfortunate it's an external server where the customer doesnt want to give me access to his cpanel. This way I have to figure it out by .htacces. Anyway, I cant access the httpd.conf :(

Answer (score 1):

This this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /www/index.php [L]
```

Comment: It first produced a directory listing. I guessed it did because the `beta/` folder was empty. I've added a simple `index.html` and it showed the index.html of the `beta/` folder, which is wrong unfortunate.

Comment: You need to describe a bit more why showing of content `/beta/index.html` without changing the URL in browser is wrong.

Comment: Do you want to just show content of www folder for `beta.domain.com` also?

Comment: Well, the thing is if you go to beta.domain.com for instance, the application index inside my www root folder sees it and shows the cms behind the website. On my own host, I simply add a subdomain and type `httpdocs` as path to go.

Comment: Honestly speaking I thought I understood your requirement when I posted my answer but now again I am getting confused. I didn't understand your last comment. Please always write in concrete terms. Like I tried to open URL: 'http://.....` and I expected this `something` but I got this `something-else`.

Comment: Its more simple then you think. When I go to `http://beta.domain.com` I want the exact same result of when I go to `http://www.domain.com`. The two domains have to stay intact in the url bar, but `beta` needs to grap the index.php etc. from the `www/` root folder.

Comment: So just to clarify, if user opens URL: `http://beta.domain.com/` in browser then load `/www/index.php` without changing the URL in browser. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm still debugging and getting closer. But if you have THE solution... I'm waiting :P

Answer (score 1):

At this moment I am helping him.
The hosting provider sucks but i can try to make it a little bit more clear.

The hosting provider build a difficult map structure but if got it, it is the following:

- htdocs

  - domainname  ----> SYMBOLIC LINK TO WWW
  - www
  - stats

If i want to add an subdomain they build the system as follow,
In the **htdocs** dir we should make a new map lets call it ***users***.
We make a dir and the directory structure is as follow:

- htdocs

  - domainname ----> SYMBOLIC LINK TO WWW
  - www
  - stats
  - ***users***

Now if we go to: *users.domainname.ext* we will get directed to the directory ***users***.

**Note:** This is the only way it's possible to make subdomains at the hosting provider.

Now what i did is add the following **.htaccess** file in the directory ***users***.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.domainname.ext/ [L]
```

This will redirect to: www.domainname.ext

Now i added in the **.htaccess** of the www dir the follow:

```
# mod-rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^users\.domainname\.ext$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The problem is that the subdomain will redirect to the new domain, and what he want's is that url bar shows: *users.domainname.ext* instead of *www.domainname.ext*

**Note:** My **.htaccess** knowledge aint much but this is as far as i can get. So i bet i have things wrong :p in it but with this i came the farest haha.

**Note 2:** The part below is used for Zend Framework to work properly!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```